# Interop working in .Net Core fails in Framework

Tags: .net, .net-core, interop

I have a wrapper for a National Instruments SPI device -- it works perfectly in .Net Core.  I want to wrap a UI waround it, so pushed the same wrapper across to .Net Framework.  There, most calls work, but one fails....I've tried different incoking signatures without luck, and quite honestly I"m dumbfounded on why it works in .Net Core 3.0, but not in Framework 4.7.2.

I also made a .Net standard wrapper project, and referenced in both applications.  That same wrapper dll works in the .Net core project, but not in Framework!  What's going on here?  It appears that .Net Core has some extra heuristics on how to handle Interop.  The question is how/why?  The .Net Core Winforms alpha plugin just isn't stable or full featured enough for me to use, and I really need it working in a standard .Net Framework project.

It works for configuring, setting DIO, etc.  But it crashes while we try and do a

```
 NI845x.ni845xSpiWriteRead(handle, SPIHandle, (uint)B.Length, B, ref ReadSize, ref ReadMsg);
```

Does anyone have any good ideas on how to get this to work, or how to troubleshoot the issue?  Thanks!

Signatures below:

```
public class NI845x
{
    public const byte kNi845x33Volts = 33; // 3.3V
    public const byte kNi845x25Volts = 25; // 2.5V
    public const byte kNi845x18Volts = 18; // 1.8V
    public const byte kNi845x15Volts = 15; // 1.5V
    public const byte kNi845x12Volts = 12; // 1.2V

    public const byte kNi845xSpiClockPolarityIdleLow = 0;// Idle Low
    public const byte kNi845xSpiClockPolarityIdleHigh = 1; // Idle High

    public const byte kNi845xSpiClockPhaseFirstEdge = 0; // First Edge
    public const byte kNi845xSpiClockPhaseSecondEdge = 1; // Second Edge

    [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xFindDevice(StringBuilder FirstDevice, ref ulong FindDeviceHandle, ref UInt32 NumberFound);

    [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xSpiWriteRead(ulong DeviceHandle, ulong ConfigurationHandle, UInt32 WriteSize, byte[] WriteData, ref UInt32 ReadSize, ref byte[] ReadData);

    [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xOpen(StringBuilder ResourceName, ref ulong DeviceHandle);


    [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xSetIoVoltageLevel(ulong DeviceHandle, byte VoltageLevel);

    [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xSpiConfigurationOpen(ref ulong SPIHandle);

    [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xSpiConfigurationSetChipSelect(ulong SPIHandle, UInt32 ChipSelect);
    [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xSpiConfigurationSetClockRate(ulong SPIHandle, UInt16 ClockRate);
    [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xSpiConfigurationSetClockPolarity(ulong SPIHandle, Int32 ClockPolarity);
    [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xSpiConfigurationSetClockPhase(ulong SPIHandle, Int32 ClockPhase);
    [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xSpiConfigurationClose(ulong DeviceHandle);
    [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xClose(ulong DeviceHandle);
    [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xDioWriteLine(ulong DeviceHandle, byte PortNumber, byte LineNumber, Int32 WriteData);
    [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xDioSetPortLineDirectionMap(ulong DeviceHandle, byte PortNumber, byte Map);

    [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xSetTimeout(ulong DeviceHandle, UInt32 Timeout);
```

Here is the .h file from NI:

```
#ifndef __Ni845x_HEADER__
#define __Ni845x_HEADER__

#ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
#endif

#if defined(WIN32)
   #define NI845X_FUNC  __stdcall
#elif defined(WIN64)
   #define NI845X_FUNC __fastcall
#elif defined(macosxU)
   #define NI845X_FUNC
#endif

#if (defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64))
   #if defined(kExportSymbols)
      #define kNI845XExport
   #else
      #define kNI845XExport
   #endif
#elif defined (macosxU)
   #if defined(kExportSymbols)
      #if ( __GNUC__ >= 4 )
         #define kNI845XExport __attribute__((visibility("default")))
      #else
         #define kNI845XExport __attribute__ ((section ("__TEXT,__export")))
      #endif
   #else
      #define kNI845XExport
   #endif
#endif

#ifdef _CVI_
   #pragma EnableLibraryRuntimeChecking
#endif

#ifndef _NI_int8_DEFINED_
#define _NI_int8_DEFINED_
   typedef char            int8;
#endif

#ifndef _NI_uInt8_DEFINED_
#define _NI_uInt8_DEFINED_
   typedef unsigned char   uInt8;
#endif

#ifndef _NI_int16_DEFINED_
#define _NI_int16_DEFINED_
   typedef short           int16;
#endif

#ifndef _NI_uInt16_DEFINED_
#define _NI_uInt16_DEFINED_
   typedef unsigned short  uInt16;
#endif

#ifndef _NI_int32_DEFINED_
#define _NI_int32_DEFINED_
   typedef long            int32;
#endif

#ifndef _NI_uInt32_DEFINED_
#define _NI_uInt32_DEFINED_
   typedef unsigned long   uInt32;
#endif

#if defined(WIN64)
   typedef unsigned long long NiHandle;
#elif defined(WIN32)
   typedef unsigned long NiHandle;
#endif

typedef struct {
   uInt32 dimSize;
   uInt8 elt[1];
} Array1DU8_t;
typedef Array1DU8_t **Array1DU8Handle_t;


#define kNi845xWarningClockRateCoerced             301700
#define kNi845xWarningSpiSampleDataIgnored         301701
#define kNi845xWarningUnknown                      301719


#define kNi845xErrorNoError                        0
#define kNi845xErrorInsufficientMemory             -301700
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidResourceName            -301701
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidClockRate               -301702
#define kNi845xErrorTooManyScriptReads             -301703
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidScriptReadIndex         -301704
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidScriptReference         -301705
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidDeviceId                -301706
#define kNi845xErrorConnectionLost                 -301707
#define kNi845xErrorTimeout                        -301708
#define kNi845xErrorInternal                       -301709
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidConfigurationReference  -301710
#define kNi845xErrorTooManyConfigurations          -301711
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidActiveProperty          -301712
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidParameter               -301713
#define kNi845xErrorResourceBusy                   -301714
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidMasterCode              -301715
#define kNi845xErrorMasterCodeAck                  -301716
#define kNi845xErrorOverCurrentError               -301718
#define kNi845xErrorSpiStreamingModeNotSupported   -301780
#define kNi845xErrorI2cSlaveModeNotSupported       -301781
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidI2cSlaveEventResponse   -301782
#define kNi845xErrorI2cSlaveEventPending           -301783

#define kNi845xErrorUnknown                        -301719


//=====================================
//
// General Errors from the device
//
//=====================================
#define kNi845xErrorBadOpcode                      -301720
#define kNi845xErrorUnknownStatus                  -301721
#define kNi845xErrorProtocolViolation              -301722
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidScript                  -301723
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidFirmware                -301724
#define kNi845xErrorIncompatibleFirmware           -301725

//=====================================
//
// SPI Errors from the device
//
//=====================================
#define kNi845xErrorMasterWriteCollision           -301730
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidSpiPortNumber           -301732
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidCsPortNumber            -301733
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidChipSelect              -301734
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidBitsPerSample           -301735

//=====================================
//
// I2C Errors from the device
//
//=====================================
#define kNi845xErrorMasterBusFreeTimeout           -301740
#define kNi845xErrorMasterCodeArbLost              -301741
#define kNi845xErrorMasterAddressNotAcknowledged   -301742
#define kNi845xErrorMasterDataNotAcknowledged      -301743
#define kNi845xErrorMasterAddressArbitrationLost   -301744
#define kNi845xErrorMasterDataArbitrationLost      -301745
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidI2CPortNumber           -301746

//=====================================
//
// DIO Errors from the device
//
//=====================================
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidDioPortNumber           -301750
#define kNi845xErrorInvalidDioLineNumber           -301751

//=====================================
//
// SPI Streaming Errors from the device
//
//=====================================
#define kNi845xErrorInStreamingMode                -301717
#define kNi845xErrorNotInStreamingMode             -301760


//=====================================
//
// SPI Function Arguments
//
//=====================================

#define kNi845xSpiClockPolarityIdleLow             0 // Idle Low
#define kNi845xSpiClockPolarityIdleHigh            1 // Idle High

#define kNi845xSpiClockPhaseFirstEdge              0 // First Edge
#define kNi845xSpiClockPhaseSecondEdge             1 // Second Edge

//=====================================
//
// DIO Function Arguments
//
//=====================================

#define kNi845xDioInput                            0 // DIO Direction Input
#define kNi845xDioOutput                           1 // DIO Direction Output

#define kNi845xDioLogicLow                         0 // DIO Level Low
#define kNi845xDioLogicHigh                        1 // DIO Level High

//=====================================
//
// Generic Function Arguments
//
//=====================================

#define kNi845xOpenDrain                           0 // Open Drain
#define kNi845xPushPull                            1 // Push Pull

#define kNi845x33Volts                             33 // 3.3V
#define kNi845x25Volts                             25 // 2.5V
#define kNi845x18Volts                             18 // 1.8V
#define kNi845x15Volts                             15 // 1.5V
#define kNi845x12Volts                             12 // 1.2V

//These defines are deprecated and the 845x Driver Type and IO Voltage Level
//should be used instead
#define kNi845xOpenDrain                           0 // Open-Drain
#define kNi845xPushPull33Volts                     1 // 3.3V Push-Pull



kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xFindDevice (
   char *     FirstDevice,
   NiHandle * FindDeviceHandle,
   uInt32 *   NumberFound
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xFindDeviceNext (
   NiHandle FindDeviceHandle,
   char *   NextDevice
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xCloseFindDeviceHandle(
   NiHandle FindDeviceHandle
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xOpen(
   char *     ResourceName,
   NiHandle * DeviceHandle
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xClose (
   NiHandle DeviceHandle
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xDeviceLock (
   NiHandle DeviceHandle
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xDeviceUnlock (
   NiHandle DeviceHandle
   );

kNI845XExport void NI845X_FUNC ni845xStatusToString(
   int32  StatusCode,
   uInt32 MaxSize,
   int8 * StatusString
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSetIoVoltageLevel(
   NiHandle DeviceHandle,
   uInt8    VoltageLevel
   );


kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSetTimeout(
   NiHandle DeviceHandle,
   uInt32   Timeout
   );


//==============================================================================
//
// SPI BASIC API FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
//
//==============================================================================


kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiWriteRead(
   NiHandle DeviceHandle,
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
   uInt32   WriteSize,
   uInt8  * WriteData,
   uInt32 * ReadSize,
   uInt8  * ReadData
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiConfigurationOpen (
   NiHandle * ConfigurationHandle
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiConfigurationClose (
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiConfigurationSetChipSelect (
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
   uInt32 ChipSelect
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiConfigurationSetClockRate (
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
   uInt16 ClockRate
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiConfigurationSetClockPolarity (
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
   int32  ClockPolarity
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiConfigurationSetClockPhase (
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
   int32  ClockPhase
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiConfigurationSetNumBitsPerSample (
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
   uInt16   NumBitsPerSample
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiConfigurationSetPort (
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
   uInt8  PortNumber
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiConfigurationGetChipSelect (
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
   uInt32 * ChipSelect
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiConfigurationGetClockRate (
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
   uInt16 * ClockRate
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiConfigurationGetClockPolarity (
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
   int32 * ClockPolarity
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiConfigurationGetClockPhase (
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
   int32 * ClockPhase
   );

int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiConfigurationGetNumBitsPerSample (
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
   uInt16 * NumBitsPerSample
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xSpiConfigurationGetPort (
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
   uInt8 * PortNumber
   );


kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xDioWritePort (
   NiHandle DeviceHandle,
   uInt8    PortNumber,
   uInt8    WriteData
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xDioReadPort (
   NiHandle DeviceHandle,
   uInt8    PortNumber,
   uInt8 *  ReadData
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xDioWriteLine (
   NiHandle DeviceHandle,
   uInt8    PortNumber,
   uInt8    LineNumber,
   int32    WriteData
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xDioReadLine (
   NiHandle DeviceHandle,
   uInt8    PortNumber,
   uInt8    LineNumber,
   int32 *  ReadData
   );

//This function has been deprecated and ni845xDioSetDriverType and
//ni845xSetIoVoltageLevel should be used instead.
kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xDioSetPortVoltageType (
   NiHandle DeviceHandle,
   uInt8    PortNumber,
   uInt8    Type
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xDioSetDriverType(
   NiHandle DeviceHandle,
   uInt8    DioPort,
   uInt8    Type
   );

kNI845XExport int32 NI845X_FUNC ni845xDioSetPortLineDirectionMap (
   NiHandle DeviceHandle,
   uInt8    PortNumber,
   uInt8    Map
   );



#ifdef __cplusplus
   }
#endif

#endif // __Ni845x_HEADER__
```

This signature seems to work in .net framework:

```
[DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern Int32 ni845xSpiWriteRead(ulong DeviceHandle, ulong ConfigurationHandle, UInt32 WriteSize, [In] byte[] WriteData,  out UInt32 ReadSize, [Out] byte[] ReadData);
```

So, is there any documentation on how/why .Net Core handles the 'out' declaration correctly?

Comment: For reference, this seems to work:


        [DllImport("Ni845x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern Int32 ni845xSpiWriteRead(ulong DeviceHandle, ulong ConfigurationHandle, UInt32 WriteSize, [In] byte[] WriteData,  out UInt32 ReadSize, [Out] byte[] ReadData);

Comment: The .NETCore version works by accident, induced by it running in 64-bit mode by default.  A .NETFramework project runs in 32-bit mode by default.  That's when the incorrect `ulong` parameter declarations start to byte badly.  A "device handle" is IntPtr, not ulong.  Best to call NI btw, you are not the first .NET programmer that needed to make this work.

Comment: Hans, I forced 32-bit and 64-bit modes without any effect on .Net Framework working or not.  If that was the issue also, why did all the DIO and other functions work perfectly fine in .Net Framework?  Just the WriteRead function didn't work.

NI isn't really helpful on this stuff -- they just point you at "hey, here's the MSDN docs on Interop, try following that."

You can also see in the .h file that the "NiHandle" is defined as a ulong in their C code.  So, we copied that across.

Comment: "unsigned long" in C is uint in C#.  "unsigned long long" is ulong.  So it needs to be IntPtr.  Not controlling the bitness correctly is a common mistake.  Don't add a new configuration, keep AnyCPU and use Project > Properties > Build tab.

Comment: The C program does control bitness -- using unsigned long long for ulong when in 64-bit more, and regular when not.  Obviously it is working correctly, as I have absolutely zero problems with the handle and its bitness; many, many functions using it work perfectly..  See the typedef for NiHandle.  While this is working, I still want to understand why .Net Core and .Net Framework, both running as x64 projects do different things for specifically the UInt32 ReadSize variable in the ni845xSpiWriteRead function, one being fine with "ref" and the other requiring "out".

Answer (score -1):

See above edit for the answer.  Just kept plugging away -- works in both now.  I guess .Net Core being cross-platform, it has more/better heuristics around PInvoke and Interop?  Is there some reason that the same isn't being used on .NEt Framework?  Is there any documentation on how/why .Net Core does this differently?